# Trouble with POST using Dio in flutter

Tags: curl, flutter, dart

I am trying to replicate the following curl command in flutter using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio).

```
$ curl -X POST -d '{"k":"cc","v":"4i8pwFwPkImsnLmIj54BYJA4Z94j0OLyl7vwKecELzYGKbM5Vra6H9T0DI"}' http://192.168.0.1/set
```

It is for setting up an IOT device that is in HotSpot mode, hence the POST to 192.168.0.1.

Here is the code that I have tried so far.

```
Future<Response> doClaimCodePost(Alice alice) async {
Dio dio = new Dio();
var data = {
  "k": "cc",
  "v": _claimCode,
};

//FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(data);

dynamic jsonData = json.encode(data);

dio.interceptors.add(alice.getDioInterceptor());

return await dio.post("http://192.168.0.1/set",
    data: jsonData,
    options: Options(contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType));
}
```

I am converting the data to JSON because that is what the body in the curl command is. I am setting the content type to form Url Encoded because that is what a curl POST command does.

I did not build this API, I am just stuck with having to use it...

I have tested the curl command, it works.

I am familiar with the [website](https://curl.trillworks.com/#dart) that magically transforms curl commands to Dart code, but I would like to use Dio.

Question: How do I replicate the curl command using Dio?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to send json, why then you use `formUrlEncodedContentType` as a type?

Try the next code:

```
final _headers = {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"
}
return await dio.post("http://192.168.0.1/set",
    data: data,
    options: Options(headers: _headers));
}
```

Comment: I am converting to JSON because that is what the body in the curl command is. I am setting the content type to form Url Encoded because that is what a curl POST command does. 

I did not build this API, I am just stuck with having to use it... 

I have tested the curl command, it works.

Comment: can you please provide the ans @DrkStr ,because i am having same kind of problem

Comment: It turned out that the problem was this https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33501#issuecomment-601605780 . So, unfortunately, I don't have a solution for you.